# Why am i getting 404 error in Github after creating a new repository?

Tags: github, http-status-code-404

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hCTVJ.png)

I have created 3 repositories with similar names, but after accessing it to see the files created it showing as 404 Error web page not found. Is this usual or it happened because of the network connection at my end?
Is it the problem of authentication? What is the work around for that? Even after creating a repository it showing 0 public repositories and when a create another with the same name, it shows me that a repository already exists.

Comment: GitHub is currently [recovering from a major outage](https://status.github.com/messages). Lots of web-facing features are currently frozen or delayed. Try again later today after things calm down.

Comment: Ok @Chris. Thanks for the update.